# Count the number of named ranges in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, named-ranges

I have 16 named ranges in a sheet .This number can change.I want the number to decide the no of slides in powerpoint.

Comment: Are the names scoped to the entire workbook or to just that sheet? You may be looking for `Worksheet.Names` or `Workbook.Names`, and then use their `.Count`.

Comment: Just to that sheet

Comment: Then use `Worksheet.Names.Count`.

Comment: I tried to use worksheet.names but i am getting a wrong value

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you're trying, thanks!

Comment: getting 7 instead of 16

Comment: Then I'm guessing some of them have workbook scope. Those won't be included in `Worksheet.Names`.

Answer (score 1):

BEcause you have a mix between "Workbook" and "Worksheet" scoped named ranges you will have to get a little crafty with your solution. Essentially 9 of your named ranges in your sheet don't belong to the sheet in which they reside. They belong to the entire workbook.

To do this you can loop through all named ranges, and see if your worksheet is named as part of the address of the named range. This may need some tweaking depending on your sheet names, but it will get you in the ballpark:

```
Sub countNamedRanges()
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim nameCount As Integer

    'loop through all names in the workbook
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Split(nm.RefersTo, "!")(0) = "=Sheet1" Then nameCount = nameCount + 1
    Next

    Debug.Print nameCount
End Sub
```